# Symfony : is it better to use a trait or an intermediary class to complete Controller one?

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I know it exists bundles like [FOSRestBundle](http://knpbundles.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) to achieve that but it can be quite complicated to use it. So I decided to create a simple `RestController` class to add more "automatized" methods to list/add/update/delete entities.

So my first question is : is it better to use a trait or an intermediary class to implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a trait depends on 2 things :

- Do you want to use `RestController` methods for some classes that doesn't depend on `Controller` ?

  *Since you will surely use some `Controller` methods to write `RestController`, I think the answer is no.*
- Do you plan to create others classes that you will have to use to complete your controllers ?

  *If the answer is yes, there are chances that you will keep `RestController` as a `Controller` inherited one and write these others classes as traits. If the answer is no, it's even clearer that `RestController` should be an intermediary one.*